# ASP.Net MVC: Localized texts with new line?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, localization

I've an Asp.Net MVC 3 website, which will be localized.

I've several resx files which contains my texts, and I've in my views some

> @My.NameSpace.Through.My.LocalizationFile.Key

But I can't make it represent the new line.

I tried:

- Shift+enter: I've got the new line in the resource file, but not in my browser
- \r\n : I see the \r\n in my browser
- \n : Same
- `<br/>` : I see the `<br/>` in my text

So what should I do to have a new line?

**Edit**: I know that I could use Html.Raw, but I just can't ask to translators to put html code in their translation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To be honest, I know it's not the nicest thing in the world, but it's fool-proof and it means your translators don't have to put any code in their translations:

Building upon the answers already given, why don't you just use `Html.Raw`, but before doing so, replacing the `\r\n` that using Shift+Enter in the resource file results in, with a `<br />`

So say for example you had the string named `Welcome` in the resource file `ApplicationMessage`, you could do:

```
@Html.Raw(ApplicationMessage.Welcome.Replace("\r\n", "<br />")
```

That will give you what you need. Here's a similar question:

[HTMLencode HTMLdecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650059/htmlencode-htmldecode)

Comment: Hum, maybe I will do an helper for that, no?

Comment: This is working nicely for us. It's not the developers who control the resource files so being able to cope (hopefully) with most cases of inserted markup is great.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the `<br />` for the line breaks and use the `@Html.Raw()` method to show the string with the line break instead of the `<br />` string.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use a combination of <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and the [CSS white-space property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) instead of potentionally opening up to XSS vulnerabilities, as you would do using `@Html.Raw()` solution.

```
<span style="white-space: pre-line">@My.NameSpace.Through.My.LocalizationFile.Key</span>
```

I don't know the specific case, but it could be that you might find that `pre-wrap` suits your case better. [Read more about the different white-space properties here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/)

Comment: Sorry, but since the question was more than 3 years ago, I'm not able to test your solution ;)

Comment: Yeah, I know it's old (guessed you had found a solution for your problem) :) Just stubled over it, and wanted to chip in for future readers ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `<br />` and render the output with `Html.Raw()`

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, thanks to mattytommo.

You can use

```
First line <br /> second line
```

in resource, or

```
resource.Replace("\r\n", "<br />")
```

in code and Shift + Enter in resource editor.

Both works fine, but you have to use

```
@Html.Raw();
```