# ASP.Net - Return user control html\text as escaped

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, user-controls

[Resolved] - see below
This is a twist on the typical question of: 'How to Get the HTML of a User Control?'
I know how to do this and I have been doing it for years but recently I became more knowledgeable about web security and I noticed that my string (aka Control HTML) is being return to the client as normal HTML and it is not encoded\escaped.  I know that I can escape it once it gets to the browser using javascript but it would be more secure if it came from the server already escaped.

Currently I am getting something back to the client like:

```
returnText = "<input id='myButton' text='whatever'>"
```

What I am looking for is:

```
returnText = "&lt;input%20id='myButton'%20text='whatever'&gt;"
```

(or something similar)

The code I am using is very typical for these types of calls. My ASCX Response is coded as:

```
StringBuilder myStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
TextWriter myTextWriter = new StringWriter(myStringBuilder);
HtmlTextWriter myWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(myTextWriter);
viewControl.RenderControl(myWriter);
strControl = myTextWriter.ToString();
```

And I am calling my control on the server using the XMLHTTPRequest object:

```
function callServer(strPage,qryParms) {
if (xmlHttp != null) { xmlHttp.abort(); }
xmlHttp = null;
var retValue = "";
xmlHttp = CreateHttpRequest();
if (xmlHttp == null) {
    alert("Your browser does not support Ajax HTTP Requests");
    return;
}
else {
    xmlHttp.open("POST", strPage, false);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            retValue = xmlHttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.send(qryParms);
}
// retValue = htmlEncode(retValue);  <--- this is where I could convert it.
return retValue;
}
```

Can I somehow intercept the Response object during the Render process to escape the string before it comes back to the browser?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTMLencode HTMLdecode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650059/htmlencode-htmldecode)

Comment: Search for `HTMLencode/HTMLdecode`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @VDWWD.  Server.HTMLencode helped but my answer was to move the extract of the control's HTML into the Render Event and then Encode it and then write it out during the render.  So the code in the Control look like this:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
   TextWriter tw = new StringWriter();
   HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);
   base.Render(htw);
   string pageSource = tw.ToString();
   //--- this is where I encode\escape the returning HTML  ----
   pageSource = Server.HtmlEncode(pageSource);
   writer.Write(pageSource);
}
```